# How to set attributes dynamically using Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The problem is: I receive JSON from the server, it contains inputs description, like: `{"name":"Audio bitrate","description":"","type":"int","value":"128","validators":{"between":{"class":"Zend\\Validator\\Between","parameters":{"min":"30","max":"500","inclusive":"1"}}}}`.

In `ng-repeat` I go through this JSON and create custom inputs (name, type, defaul value). Some inputs have validators, rewritten in angular with derictives to check inputs before sending. In this case I need to add `between` as a derictive name, `min="30"`, `max="500"` and `inclusive="1"` to input attributes, i.e.

`<input between type="number" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="{{value.description|translate}}" ng-model="preset.parameters.common[parameter]" ng-init="preset.parameters.common[parameter] = (value.value - 0)" min="30" max="500" inclusive="1">`

Different inputs might have different validators or none of them (no `ng-attr-*` and `C-class` directives), I did try to bind attributes with `{{value.key}}`, it doesn't work.

How can I achieve my goal of dynamic attribute binding? Thank you.

Comment: is all your attributes related to input field only or there can be possibility of select or something else also ?